# What is the functional derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I do not understand, if the functional derivative is

- a function
- a generalized function (distribution)
- a functional itself
- something different (see Euler-Lagrange)

To clarify my question, I have seen multiple instances of functional derivative definitions

**Functionals**

When the Functional gets Taylor expanded (here using a "good" $\eta(x)$) we get

$$F[y(x)+\epsilon \eta(x)] = F[y(x)] + \frac{dF[y(x) + \epsilon \eta(x)]}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0}\cdot \epsilon + ...$$

as I understood, the term on the RHS is the functional derivative. But since the LHS is a functional and the RHS is a functional + a real number ($\epsilon$) times the functional derivative, I conclude that the functional derivative must also be a functional.

**Functions/Distributions**

The english wikipedia page [2] states, that the functional derivative is defined as

$$\int{\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho} (x)\phi(x)dx}=\frac{dF[\rho(x) + \epsilon \phi(x)]}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0}$$

notice that the RHS is equivalent to the functional derivative defined above. However, it is $$\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho} (x)$$ that is defined to be the functional derivative, and not the RHS (as I concluded above). Therefore I may as well assume that the functional derivative is a function/distribution.

**Something else**

The solution to the Euler-Lagrange Equation (one dimensional for simplicity) given an Energy Functional $J[y] = \int_{a}^{b}{L(x,y,y')}$ is

$$\frac{\delta J}{\delta y} = \frac{dL}{dy} - \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dL}{dy'}) = 0$$

here, $\frac{\delta J}{\delta y}$ is supposedly the fractional derivative of the integral, which has to be stationary. RHS tells me that the functiona derivative is a differential equation - which has a function as a solution - but I am now completely unsure what the functional derivative in itself actualy is.

I have seen multiple viewpoints, each and every one cluttering my intuition even more. For instance the wikipedia article claims that $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho} (x)$ has to be seen as a "gradient" (which is a vector in multivariate calculus), while $\int{\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho} (x)\phi(x)dx}$ has to be thought of like a directional derivative (which is the inner product of the gradient and the direction vector). But since there are no bounds on the integral the "directional derivative" is also a function, or am I mistaken?

[1] http://lab.sentef.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Tutorial_02.pdf page 4

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170217025324/https://www2.ee.washington.edu/techsite/papers/documents/UWEETR-2008-0001.pdf) short article its very well explained

Answer (score 5):

The expression
$\delta F[\rho,\phi] := \frac{dF[\rho(x) + \epsilon \phi(x)]}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0},$
when defined, is a functional of $\rho$ and $\phi.$ The dependency on $\rho$ is usually non-linear, while the dependency on $\phi$ is usually linear.

If the expression is restricted to $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and the dependency on $\phi$ is linear, then the mapping $\phi \mapsto \delta F[\rho,\phi]$ is usually a distribution. Often this distribution can be [identified with a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Functions_and_measures_as_distributions).

Thus, $\delta F[\rho,\phi]$ is a functional, usually a distribution, and often a function.

Often we have $F[\rho] = \int L(x, \rho(x), \rho'(x)) \, dx$ for some Lagrangian $L.$ Then, if $\phi$ vanishes on the boundary of the domain, 
$$
\delta F[\rho,\phi] = \int \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \rho} \phi(x) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \rho'} \phi'(x) \right) dx
= \int \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \rho} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \rho'} \right) \phi(x) \, dx.
$$
In this case, $\delta F[\rho,\phi]$ is given by an integral of a function (the parenthesis) times $\phi.$ Thus this falls into the case "Often this distribution can be [identified with a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Functions_and_measures_as_distributions)".

Comment: "Thus, δF[ρ,ϕ] is a functional, usually a distribution, and often a function." - this confuses me
Did you mean the mapping from $\phi$ or the $\delta F$ itself (in the case of distribution/function?

Comment: @MuradBabayev. The mapping $\phi \mapsto \delta F[\rho,\phi]$ is usually a distribution, and this is often given by an integration against a function, $\phi \mapsto \int f_\rho(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx.$

Comment: Isn't $\phi$ just an arbitrary function from the same space as $\rho$? Why are we assuming that it vanishes on the boundary? Do we need to consider $\rho$ also vanishing on the boundary for this to be the case?

Comment: @lightxbulb. It's a special case that is often used.

Comment: @md2perpe Do you have a suggestion for a reference that discusses this in more details? I am aware for instance that when we look for weak solutions, even the definition of weak derivative requires that the boundary terms vanish, so one considers test functions that vanish on the Dirichlet boundary. Is this related in some way?

Comment: @lightxbulb. That's certainly related. If the function vanishes on the boundary (sometimes also vanishing derivatives are required) then boundary terms from the integration disappear. Unfortunately I don't have any references other than Wikipedia and any book about calculus of variations.

Answer (score 2):

**Functionals of Smooth Fields**

Suppose you have a smooth multivariable scalar field ${f}\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Then a functional ${W}\in\mathrm{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$ is a mapping from $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that takes the form
\begin{align*}
{W}[f]=\int\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]{\,}\mathrm{d}^{n}{x}{\,}{,}
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]$ is the Lagrangian, that depends both on the coordinate variables ${x}$, as well as functionally depends on the field in coordinates ${f(x)}$ and its consecutive derivatives $\big\lbrace\frac{\partial{f(x)}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha}},\frac{\partial^{2}{f(x)}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\partial{x}^{\alpha_{2}}},\frac{\partial^{3}{f(x)}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\partial{x}^{\alpha_{2}}\partial{x}^{\alpha_{3}}},\cdots\big\rbrace$. Now, rather then looking at the variational derivative as a limit, try thinking of $\frac{\delta}{\delta{f(x)}}\in\mathrm{Der}(\mathrm{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})))$ as the derivative operator on $\mathrm{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$,
similar to how $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}^{\alpha}}\in\mathrm{Der}(\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$ is the derivative operator on $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, that satisfies the algebra
\begin{align*}
(\mathrm{I}){\,\,}&\frac{\delta({a}\mathcal{L}_{\alpha}(x)[f(x)]+{b}\mathcal{L}_{\beta}(x)[f(x)])}{\delta{f(y)}}={a}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_{\alpha}(x)[f(x)]}{\delta{f(y)}}+{b}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_{\beta}(x)[f(x)]}{\delta{f(y)}}{\quad}{a}{,}{b}\in\mathbb{R}{\,}{,}\\
(\mathrm{II}){\,\,}&\frac{\delta(\mathcal{L}_{\alpha}(x)[f(x)]{\,}\mathcal{L}_{\beta}(x)[f(x)])}{\delta{f(y)}}=\mathcal{L}_{\alpha}(x)[f(x)]\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_{\beta}(x)[f(x)]}{\delta{f(y)}}+{\,}\mathcal{L}_{\beta}(x)[f(x)]\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}_{\alpha}(x)[f(x)]}{\delta{f(y)}}{\,}{,}\\
(\mathrm{III}){\,\,}&\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}(x)[g(f(x))]}{\delta{f(y)}}=\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}(x)[g(f(x))]}{\delta{g(f(y))}}\frac{\mathrm{d}{g(z)}}{\mathrm{d}{z}}\bigg\vert_{{z}={f(y)}}{\,}{.}
\end{align*}
The functional derivative can now be written as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta{W}[f]}{\delta{f(y)}}&=\int\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]}{\delta{f(y)}}{\,}\mathrm{d}^{n}{x}=\int\sum_{{m}={0}}^{\infty}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(x)}/\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\frac{\delta}{\delta{f(y)}}\bigg[\frac{\partial^{m}{f(x)}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg]{\,}\mathrm{d}^{n}{x}\\
&=\int\sum_{{m}={0}}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(x)}/\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\frac{\delta{f(x)}}{\delta{f(y)}}\bigg]\\
&+(-{1})^{m}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(x)}/\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg]\frac{\delta{f(x)}}{\delta{f(y)}}\bigg){\,}\mathrm{d}^{n}{x}{\,}{,}
\end{align*}
where $\frac{\delta{f(x)}}{\delta{f(y)}}=\Delta({x}-{y})$ is the Dirac delta function that is simply defined as
\begin{align*}
\int{f(x)}\Delta({x}-{y}){\,}\mathrm{d}^{n}{x}={f(y)}.
\end{align*}
Furthermore, since $\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\big[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(x)}/\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\Delta({x}-{y})\big]$ is a total derivative, it vanishes when being integrated over a set without boundary. And with all that combined, the functional derivative finally becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta{W}[f]}{\delta{f(y)}}&=\int\sum_{{m}={0}}^{\infty}(-{1})^{m}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(x)[f(x)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(x)}/\partial{x}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{x}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg]\Delta({x}-{y}){\,}\mathrm{d}^{n}{x}\\
&=\sum_{{m}={0}}^{\infty}(-{1})^{m}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial{y}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{y}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(y)[f(y)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(y)}/\partial{y}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{y}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg]{\,}{.}
\end{align*}

**Euler Lagrange Equation**

The Euler Lagrange equation of an action is given by simply setting the variational derivative of the functional equal to zero, being
\begin{align*}
{0}\equiv\frac{\delta{W}[f]}{\delta{f(y)}}=\sum_{{m}={0}}^{\infty}(-{1})^{m}\frac{\partial^{m}}{\partial{y}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{y}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(y)[f(y)]}{\partial\partial^{m}{f(y)}/\partial{y}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\partial{y}^{\alpha_{m}}}\bigg]{\,}{.}
\end{align*}

**Application in classical mechanics**

In classical mechanics, the action functional of a curve has the form
\begin{align*}
{W}[x]=\int\mathcal{L}(t)[x(t)]{\,}\mathrm{d}{t}=\int\bigg(\frac{m}{2}\bigg\Vert\frac{\mathrm{d}{x(t)}}{\mathrm{d}{t}}\bigg\Vert^{2}-{m}\Phi(x(t))\bigg){\,}\mathrm{d}{t}{\,}{.}
\end{align*}
With the standard Euler Lagrange equation
\begin{align*}
{0}\equiv\frac{\delta{W}[x]}{\delta{{x}^{\alpha}(t)}}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(t)[x(t)]}{\partial{{x}^{\alpha}(t)}}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}{t}}\bigg[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(t)[x(t)]}{\partial\mathrm{d}{{x}^{\alpha}(t)}/\mathrm{d}{t}}\bigg]=-{m}\frac{\partial\Phi(x(t))}{\partial{{x}^{\alpha}(t)}}-{m}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}{{x}^{\alpha}(t)}}{\mathrm{d}{t}^{2}}{\,}{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to the site. We appreciate this detailed answer

Comment: Aren't you missing a summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ over the n variables?